# What are .seh_* assembly commands that gcc outputs?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

I use gcc -S for a hello world program.  What are the 5 .seh_ commands?  I can't seem to find much info at all about them when I search.

```
    .file   "hi.c"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "Hello World\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (rubenvb-4.8.0) 4.8.0"
    .def    puts;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Comment: "SEH" is Structured Exception Handling, a Windows feature.  They were working on implementing it in 4.8, sounds like they're done.  There's a blurb about it [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are `gas`'s implementation of MASM's [frame handling pseudos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235217.aspx) for generating an executable's .pdata and .xdata sections (structured exception handling stuff).  Also check out [Raw Pseudo Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235231.aspx).  Apparently if your code might be in the stack during an SEH unwind operation, you are expected to use these.

I found *slightly* more information at https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-08/msg00193.html.  This thread seems to be the original checkin to `gas` to add support for all the .set_* pseudo ops.

> I would like to show the patch for .pdata and .xdata generation of
>   pe-coff targets via gas, and to get some feed-back. This patch
>   includes support for arm, ppc, arm, sh (3&4), mips, and x64. As for
>   x86 there is no OS support for runtime function information, I spared
>   this part. It would just increase executable size for x86 PE and there
>   is no real gain for this target.
>
> **Short overview:**
>   There are at the moment three different function entry formats preset.
>
> The first is the MIPS one. The second version is for ARM, PPC, SH3,
>   and SH4 mainly for Windows CE.  The third is the IA64 and x64 version.
>   Note, the IA64 isn't implemented yet, but to find information about
>   it, please see specification about IA64 on
>   http://download.intel.com/design/Itanium/Downloads/245358.pdf file.
>
> The first version has just entries in the pdata section: BeginAddress,
>   EndAddress, ExceptionHandler, HandlerData, and PrologueEndAddress.
>   Each value is a pointer to the corresponding data and has size of 4
>   bytes.
>
> The second variant has the following entries in the pdata section. 
>   BeginAddress, PrologueLength (8 bits), EndAddress (22 bits),
>   Use-32-bit-instruction (1 bit), and Exception-Handler-Exists (1 bit). 
>   If the FunctionLength is zero, or the Exception-Handler-Exists bit is
>   true, a DATA_EH block is placed directly before function entry.
>
> The third version has a function entry block of BeginAddress (RVA),
>   EndAddress (RVA), and UnwindData (RVA). The description of the
>   prologue, excepetion-handler, and additional SEH data is stored within
>   the UNWIND_DATA field in the xdata section.
>
> **.seh_proc <fct_name>**
>   This specifies, that a SEH block begins for the function <fct_name>. This is valid for all
>   targets.
>
> **.seh_endprologue**
>   By this pseudo the location of the prologue end-address (taken by the current code address of the appearance of
>   this pseudo). Valid for all targets.
>
> **.seh_handler <handler>[,<handler-data>]**
>   This pseudo specifies the handler function to be used. For version 2 the
>   handler-data field specifies the user optional data block. For version
>   3 the handler-data field can be a rva to user-data (for FHANDLER), if
>   the name is @unwind the UHANDLER unwind block is generated, and if it
>   is @except (or not specified at all) EHANDLER exception block is
>   generated.
>
> **.seh_eh**
>   This pseudo is used for version 2 to indicate the location of the function begin in assembly. Here the PDATA_EH data is
>   may stored to.
>
> **.seh_32/.seh_no32**
>   This pseudos are just used for version 2 (see above for description). At the moment it defaults to no32, if not
>   specified.
>
> **.seh_endproc**
>   By this pseudo the end of the SEH block is specified.
>
> **.seh_setframe <reg>,<offset>**
>   By this pseudo the frame-register and the offset (value between 0-240 with 16-byte
>   alignment) can be specified. This is just used by version 3.
>
> **.seh_stackalloc <size>**
>   By this stack allocation in code is described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_pushreg <reg>**
>   By this a general register push in code is described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_savereg <reg>**
>   By this a general register save to memory in code is described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_savemm <mm>**
>   By this a mm register save to memory in code is described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_savexmm**
>   By this a xmm register save to memory in code is described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_pushframe**
>   By this information about entry kind can be described for version 3.
>
> **.seh_scope <begin>,<end>,<handler>,<jump>**
>   By this SCOPED entries for unwind or exceptions can be specified for
>   version 3. This is just valid for UHANDLE and EHANDLER xdata
>   descriptor and a global handler has to be specified. For handler and
>   jump arguments, names of @1,@0, and @null can be used and they are
>   specifying that a constant instead of a rva has to be used.

There is also some hard-core discussion of .xdata and .pdata (along with a bunch of links) at https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2009-04/msg00181.html.

Answer (score 10):

I stopped them from being output by using:

```
gcc -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables hi.c
```

so I can look that up.  But I'm happy with just not having them output anymore.

Answer (score 2):

They seem related to exception handling. That's all I could find.

http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/external/gpl3/binutils/dist/gas/config/obj-coff-seh.h